# Script for awscli check not working with crontab schedule

Tags: cron, environment-variables, aws-cli, crontrigger, sles

I have written a small code snippet to check the aws cli version

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [ -e "/usr/local/bin/aws" ];
then
    myAWS="/usr/local/bin/aws"
else
    myAWS="/usr/bin/aws"
fi

myCmd=("${myAWS} --version")

echo "$myCmd"

message=$($myCmd)

echo "$message"
```

Now while running this manually with root user I am able to run this script without any issue . Post our aws cli upgrade when we try to schedule this script via crontab for root user ( schedule given below)

57 21 * * * /rough/scripts/log/test.sh > /rough/scripts/log/test.log 2>&1

I face the below error , can you suggest??? I  have reinstalled the aws cli but to no effect.

I understand crontab runtime environment is different than when you  run a script manually but can I check whats the runtime environment that cronjob picks up.
The user is root and OS is SLES.

[[Error as below]]

```
/usr/local/bin/aws --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aws", line 19, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "awscli/clidriver.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "awscli/help.py", line 20, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "docutils/core.py", line 23, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 493, in exec_module
  File "docutils/io.py", line 43, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode characters in position 4-6: surrogates not allowed
[24036] Failed to execute script 'aws' due to unhandled exception!`
```

Comment: It would like be the result of the AWS CLI upgrade that was performed. Perhaps uninstall and reinstall the AWS CLI while acting as the root user.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein- already did that , no luck :(

Answer (score 1):

I finally was able to fix this.The issue was with a different locale being picked up by the crontab runtime environment in comparison to the environment of the user running the script.

The fix was to include the correct locale in the crontab file before the crontab schedule.

LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8

- - - - - 